# Same Layout but different result

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem. With the same layout, one time it's charging on launch and second time it's by an intent.

**Good**:

[image: Good View]

**Bad**:

[image: Bad Layout]

Here is my MainActivity. I implement the drawer and so on... :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    
//Get the list of shoes
    new getSneakers().execute();
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


//@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.all_sneak) {
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
        mainLayout.removeAllViews();
        mainLayout.addView(layout);
        new getSneakers().execute();

    } else if (id == R.id.my_colleciton) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_want) {

    }    
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here is my `content_main`. This is included by the app bar `main` and it's showing the shoes. For me the problem is coming from here, but I try something and it changes nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.etml.sneakcolleciton.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:background="#eaecea">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My `Activit_Main` is the simple menu where I include the `app_main_main` whose content one includes where the `RecyclerView` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:background="#eaecea">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the `app_bar_main` where I include the `content_main` where is the list with the shoes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    tools:context="com.etml.sneakcolleciton.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: paste your xml file where imageview is

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/WTJv6 here, the code is too long

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

replace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.etml.sneakcolleciton.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:background="#eaecea">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>`
```

with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.etml.sneakcolleciton.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:background="#eaecea">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: Post your included layout

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

   <RecyclerView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Bro i m not talking about this layout
talking about onCreateViewHolder() where you inflate showing data layout

Comment: public AdapterR.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_data, parent, false);
        return new AdapterR.ViewHolder(view);
    }

in your adapter

Comment: LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. main_container);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.addView(layout);
            new getSneakers().execute();

Comment: I do it on onNavigationItemselected

Comment: Post Your content_main.xml